# Flatlist is not properly refetched after clearing text from my search bar

Tags: javascript, react-native, search

The Code represents a expo screen that displays cryptocurrencies.

The problem is that the coin list is not properly refetched after clearing text from my search bar. It works fine until I delete the last letter and I'm not sure how to fix it. I highlighted the code that I think it needs to be changed. Thank you.

```
 data={coins.filter((coin) =>
            coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase()) ||
            coin.symbol.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())
        )}
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdm6h.jpg)

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { FlatList, RefreshControl, View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import { coinsListRequest } from "../../services";
import CoinItem from "../../components/CoinItem";

const HeaderText = styled.Text`
  font-family: "Roboto_400Regular";
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
`;

const MarketsScreen = () => {
  const [coins, setCoins] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const fetchCoinsList = async (page) => {
    if (isLoading) {
      return;
    }
    setIsLoading(true);
    const coinsData = await coinsListRequest(page);
    coinsData.length && setCoins((prevState) => [...prevState, ...coinsData]);
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  const refetchCoinsList = async () => {
    if (isLoading) {
      return;
    }
    setIsLoading(true);
    const coinsData = await coinsListRequest();
    setCoins(coinsData);
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCoinsList();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>
                Markets
          </Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.searchInput}
            placeholder="Search a Coin"
            placeholderTextColor="#fff"
            onChangeText={(text) => text && setSearch(text)}
          />
      </View>
      <FlatList
        data={coins.filter((coin) =>
            coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase()) ||
            coin.symbol.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())
        )}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        keyExtractor={(item) => `c-${item.id}`}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <CoinItem coinData={item} />}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={isLoading}
            onRefresh={refetchCoinsList}
            tintColor="white"
          />
        }
        onEndReached={() => {
          fetchCoinsList(coins.length / 50 + 1);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default MarketsScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  title: {
    fontFamily: "Roboto_400Regular",
    fontSize: 25,
    color: 'white',
  },
  searchInput: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 15,
    width: "40%",
    borderBottomColor: 'white',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issues is in here `onChangeText={(text) => text && setSearch(text)}`. Lets take an example, suppose search has "lorem" as a value so when you delete the last item -> l, onchangetext provides you "" in text and text is false here, so your setSearch(text) doesn't executed. So try to replace this piece of code below and if you need validation with entered value keep it in the function when you doing any operation with the entered value like

```
if(search==="") return;
```

Updated TextInput

```
<TextInput
  value={search}
  style={styles.searchInput}
  placeholder="Search a Coin"
  placeholderTextColor="#fff"
  onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text)}
 />
```

also don't forget to add extradata in FlatList for list performance
checkout here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist